# in split view how to adjust the views to the screen when app launched in landscape mode

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

i am displaying master view and detail view in portrait mode of split view controller ,
i hav not used the pop up window to show master view as like most of hte ipad apps showing...

i am facing issue with orientation when my app is launching in land scape mode i cannot able to adjust that to view

Answer (score 0):

the width is fixed

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html

Answer (score 0):

In the out of the box UISplitView the width is fixed.

Alterntively you could use the `MGSplitViewController` it is a Custom SplitViewController and one of the features is width customisation.

It can be Found here: http://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController

Answer (score 0):

Only the UIImageView or the whole view ?

I faced the problem with my UIImageViews , then I solved it like :

Interface Builder -> UIImageView Size Inspector -> Autosizing

Select all the Outer Bars and Un-Select all the inner bars.

Hope it will help :)